# How to add back commas into string python regex?

Tags: python, regex

So I have a string that contains multiple dates like March 4 1998, but they are all missing commas.
How, using python can I go through and add back commas into these strings. The dates are part of a large paragraph.

Comment: Are all the dates of exactly this format?

Comment: Well ya but they all have different years, months, and days. And they are all part of this large paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be simple:

```
>>> s = "dates like March 4 1998, but they are all missing commas"
>>> regex = re.compile("""
... (January|February|March|April|June|July|August|September|October|
...  November|December)[ ]([0-9]{1,2})[ ]([0-9]{4})""", re.X)
>>> regex.sub(r"\1 \2, \3", s)
'dates like March 4, 1998, but they are all missing commas'
```

Comment: No i mean like "Today is March 4 1999 and tomorrow is March 5 1999"